# MVC4 @Html.Checkboxfor issue with Ajax call

Tags: ajax, checkbox

I was working with MVC CheckBox for.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.IsActive, new { @id = "IsActive",@checked = "checked" })

if ($('#frmmenu').valid())
{
    //alert("MenuTitle=" + $("#MenuTitle").val() + "&OrderNumber=" + $("#OrderNumber").val() + "&IsActive=" + $("#IsActive").val());

    alert("MenuTitle=" + $("#MenuTitle").val() + "&OrderNumber=" + $("#OrderNumber").val() + "&IsActive=" + $("#IsActive").val());
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/api/MenuWebApi/SetMenu',
        data: "MenuTitle=" + $("#MenuTitle").val() + "&OrderNumber=" + $("#OrderNumber").val() + "&IsActive=" + $("#IsActive").val(),
        success: function (data)
        {
            if (data.Success == true)
            {
                //window.location = '/Profile/UserProfile';
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //window.location = JsErrorAction;
        },
        dataType: "json",
        headers:
        {
            'RequestVerificationToken': JsTokenHeaderValue
        }

    });
}
return false;
```

with passing data when checkbox is checked it is giving true value, but if unchecked then it will give true value not false, how could i  do?

please help me anyone.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
var isActive = ($('#IsActive').attr('checked') == 'checked');
// $('#IsActive').attr('checked') will return 
// 'checked' or undefined - if not checked/not containing 'checked' attribute
```